# javascript callback : undefined global variable

Tags: javascript, scope, callback

I have a problem with this code.

```
var uls = document.getElementsByClassName("gal");

for (var i = 0; i < uls.length; i++) {

    // impossible to pass uls[i] as callback argument (undefined in callback)
    uls[i].addEventListener("click", function() { openSlideShowModal(uls[i].tagName);} );
}
```

I have the error :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of undefined

I can't explained why *uls[i]* is *undefined* as it is global. I know that there's no use of it because it could be accessible by *this* in the callback. But i found this incomprehensible error by chance.

Moreover if i modify slightly i no longer have an error

```
var uls = document.getElementsByClassName("gal");

for (var i = 0; i < uls.length; i++) {

    tagName = uls[i].tagName;
    // impossible to pass uls[i] as callback argument (undefined in callback)
    uls[i].addEventListener("click", function() { openSlideShowModal(tagName);} );
}
```

Comment: OK i = 1 in my code, that's why i have an 'undefined' (only one ul)

Answer (score 0):

A bind this should help you out getting the function back into the same context where ever it is being called.

```
function() { 
    openSlideShowModal(uls[i].tagName);
}.bind(this)
```